# Read from a file in a 2d integer array

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ coding, and I need to read from a file of this structure:

```
8
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
5
```

i need to read the numbers into 2 different int variables (8 and 5) and the rest in a 2d int array.

What i have so far:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("f.in");
ofstream gout("g.out");

int a[30][30], n, x;

int main()
{
    fin>>n;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            fin>>a[i][j];

        }
    fin>>x; c[1]=x; s[x]=1;
//other function call .....

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        gout<<c[i]<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

The code is building and compiling however, it doesn't read from the file.

Comment: Arrays on C++ are origin 0. They index from 0 to n-1, so `for(i=1; i<=n; i++)` starts one too late and often runs one past the end.

Comment: When you trace it with a debugger, at what point does it behave differently than you expect?

Comment: I recommend making certain that `fin` is open and `gout` is where you expect it to be. Since you are using a Relative Paths you may run into problems with the Working Directory

Comment: I also recommend testing every IO transaction for success. If a stream read fails and you don't check, you won't know until the output is garbage.

Comment: The sooner you start eliminating `#include<conio.h>` from your programming, the better off you are. DOS was a long time ago. The sooner you make friends with the C++ containers, the sooner your life as a programmer will become easier. See [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and think `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: The input does not match the code. You read the first number, then expect to have a square matrix of that size, in the code. But the text has n=8, followed by a 4x5 array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck, then let's take it step-by-step.

First *Do Not Hardcode Filenames*. (and don't use *magic-number*, e.g. any number stuck in your code instead of properly defining a constant for it). `ifstream fin("f.in");` What if you have another file `"f.int2"` that you want to read? That is what function parameters are for. For `main()` you have `argc` that tells you how many arguments are given, and `argv`, an array of pointers to each of the args (followed by a terminating `NULL` pointer). Use them. For example:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
...
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1-argument available for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficnent input\nusage: " << argv[0]
                << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream fin (argv[1]);    /* open filename given by 1st argument */
```

(**note:** the first argument value, `argv[0]`, is always the executable name being run, so you must check for a total of two arguments to ensure there is something in `argv[1]`)

Next **validate** that the file is open for reading, e.g.

```
    if (!fin.good()) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

Now let's turn to reading your input file, what I'll name `2dintarr+stuff.txt` and I'll put it in the `dat` subdirectory, e.g.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/2dintarr+stuff.txt
8
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
5
```

The `"+stuff"` being the `8` and `5` that have nothing to do with the 2D array of values you want to store. The `8` and `5` are easily dealt with simply by reading the entire line into a `string`, creating a `stringstream` from the line, and then looping and reading integers from the stringstream until you run out of numbers to read. If you only read one value before you run out of numbers, then you can simply store those values somewhere that is not your array (like in a vector called `notarr`). If there is more than one value in the line, then store all values in a vector, and add that vector as a row in a vector of vectors.

Sounds complicated, but it's not. C++ provides containers, that allow you to add and remove values to them much like you would an array, but better, the containers automatically manage the memory for you, allocating more as needed, and freeing the memory when there are no more references to the container. One of those containers is a `vector` which you can think of as simply a 1D array. C++ allows containers to contain other containers. So when you need a 2D array, what you want is a vector of vectors.

In your case you need a `string` to hold each line of data you read, you need your vector of vector `arr` for your array, and then another single vector to hold the `"+stuff"` that is not part of your array -- called `notarr`. The declarations would be as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
...
    std::string line;                       /* string for reading each line */
    std::vector<std::vector <int>> arr;     /* vector<vector<int>> (2D arr) */
    std::vector<int> notarr;                /* vector to hold single values */
```

Now all that remains is reading each line, and then creating a stringstream from the line so you can loop reading integers from the line until your run out of numbers to read. (you can't just use `fin >> number;` in a loop because reading iostream will skip *leading whitespace*, `'\n'` being whitespace, so attempting to use `>>` on the file stream itself -- you could never tell how many values were in the line, `>>` would just skip the `'\n'` as whitespace.

How to fix that? Use a `stringstream`. Basically a stringstream is equivalent to a buffer that can be used as a stream. So you read a line of data from the file, create a stringstream from it, and then loop `while (ss >> value)` which will stop when it reaches the end of the stringstream (i.e. buffer) because there is nothing else to read allowing you to determine how many values were contained in the original line. (you will use this technique over-and-over again)

Example:

```
    while (getline (fin, line)) {  /* read each remaining data line */
        int i;
        std::vector<int> tmp;           /* vector<int> for each line */
        std::stringstream ss (line);    /* stringstream to read from */
        while (ss >> i)                 /* read int from stringstream */
            tmp.push_back(i);           /* add to tmp vector */
        if (tmp.size() == 1)            /* if single value in line */
            notarr.push_back(i);        /* add value to notarr */
        else if (tmp.size() > 1)        /* if multiple values in line */
            arr.push_back(tmp);         /* add tmp vector to arr */
    }
```

Above you simply read each line into `line`, the create the stringsteam `ss`, then using a temporary vector `tmp`, load each value into the temporary vector. When done you just check how many elements are in the `tmp` vector. If one, it's the `8` or `5`, add it to the vector `notarr`, if it is more than one, `tmp` contains a row of your 2D array, so add it do `arr`. That's it.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string line;                       /* string for reading each line */
    std::vector<std::vector <int>> arr;     /* vector<vector<int>> (2D arr) */
    std::vector<int> notarr;                /* vector to hold single values */

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1-argument available for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficnent input\nusage: " << argv[0]
                << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream fin (argv[1]);    /* open filename given by 1st argument */
    if (!fin.good()) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (fin, line)) {  /* read each remaining data line */
        int i;
        std::vector<int> tmp;           /* vector<int> for each line */
        std::stringstream ss (line);    /* stringstream to read from */
        while (ss >> i)                 /* read int from stringstream */
            tmp.push_back(i);           /* add to tmp vector */
        if (tmp.size() == 1)            /* if single value in line */
            notarr.push_back(i);        /* add value to notarr */
        else if (tmp.size() > 1)        /* if multiple values in line */
            arr.push_back(tmp);         /* add tmp vector to arr */
    }

    std::cout << "2D array of values:\n\n";
    for (auto& i : arr) {           /* loop over rows */
        for (auto& j : i)           /* loop over each value in column */
            std::cout << " " << j;  /* output value */
        std::cout << '\n';          /* tidy up with newline */
    }

    std::cout << "\nSingle-values:\n\n";
    for (auto& i: notarr)           /* output values not part of array */
        std::cout << " " << i;      
    std::cout << '\n';              /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

(**note:** the vector container provides the `.push_back()` and `.size()` member functions to let you add a value to the vector and to tell you have many elements are contained within it, respectively.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rd2dintarr+stuff dat/2dintarr+stuff.txt
2D array of values:

 1 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 0

Single-values:

 8 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.